# Error when launching app on device

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I get this error when I try to run the app:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException:
duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class
```

The Manifest contains this section:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    tools:ignore="OldTargetApi"
    tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.espresso,
                           android.support.v7.appcompat,
                           android.support.mediacompat,
                           android.support.v4,
                           android.support.fragment,
                           android.support.coreui,
                           android.support.coreutils,
                           android.support.graphics.drawable,
                           android.support.compat">
    </uses-sdk>
```

These are the dependencies in the gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
//        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
//    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Any ideas what I need to do?

I'm new to Android development, so please assume that I know nothing...

Comment: share your `Build.gradle`

Comment: You are building same library multiple time ....

Comment: I gathered that from the words 'duplicate entry'... What I need to understand is why/where, and more importantly how to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same issue and it was like the appcompat-v7 was including support-v4 also so it was creating duplicated entries.

I resolved that using by excluding the v4 support library from it :

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Comment: That worked - it removed the error, but replaced it with: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/SearchView$10.class

Comment: update appcompat to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'